# Getting error 'No matching client found for package name and Execution failed for task app:processDebugGoogleServices'in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I think I have done every thing correct created new app AbcXyz using react native
and also create a project for realtime database as AbcXyz and register adroid app as com.AbcXyz and downloaded the json file now I am getting this error
`Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> No matching client found for package name 'com.abcxyz' in D:\codes\AbcXyz\android\app\google-services.json`

I have changed the 'com.AbcXyz' in json as below in all small letters

```
client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:xxx:android:xxx",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.abcxyz"
        }
      },
```

now the error gone and app starts normaly but now I am not able to add anything to database

Answer (score 0):

People forget to tell this, just copy the `applicationId` from the app build gradle to register new app in firebase database. We tends to create same name as  created app which is not correct.